# Get signature key for aws s3 (ruby)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to run a script to get the hexadecimal representation of the aws signing key. But instead, I'm getting this on the terminal:

```
???>?^?c???w?,????-??e??$C
```

What's wrong with my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'openssl'
def getSignatureKey key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName
    kDate = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', "AWS4" + key, dateStamp)
    kRegion = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, regionName)
    kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")

    kSigning
end

puts getSignatureKey('wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY','20170110', 'us-west-1', 's3')
```

Comment: Ruby conventions strongly encourage people to use method names like `get_signature_key`, all lower-case with an underscore for separators where required. Capitals have significant meaning in Ruby and are reserved for `ClassName`, `ModuleName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` type situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values from [`digest`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html) are documented as being binary in nature. If you want them human-readable then you must use `hexdigest` or convert them yourself.